# Blocks in a ledger? Ledgers in a block?

Tags: blockchain

I got a question about blockchain model with hyperledger-fabric.

I'm not sure if blocks in a ledger or ledgers in a block of channel (or peer).
I read some documents from http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/ or blogs.
but I'm still confused..
Which one is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ledger is composed of blocks. And each channel has its own ledger. And every peer can have multiple ledgers and participate in multiple channels.

Answer (score 0):

[This is diagram on hyperledger fabric network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugDFx.png)

In the diagram, You can easily recognize. Hyperledger network has multiple channels, a channel has multiple peers, a peer includes multiple ledgers and multiple chaincodes.